# How to post files in Swagger (OpenAPI)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am using Swagger to document my REST services. One of my services requires a CSV file to be uploaded. I added the following to the `parameters` section in my JSON API definition:

```json
{
       "name": "File",
       "description": "The file in zip format.",
       "paramType": "body",
       "required": true,
       "allowMultiple": false,
       "dataType": "file"
}
```

and now I see the file upload option on my Swagger UI page. But when I select a file and click "try it out", I get the following error:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object in jquery-1.8.0.min.js (line 2)

The page is continuously processing and I am not getting any response.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: can you try it without the last comma behind "file"?

Comment: @Soc : Please ignore that comma, it is just a typo mistake.

Comment: maybe you can try to debug this the following way: (maybe use newer query version), use a not-minimized version of jquery and take a look into JS console (maybe set a breakpoint) and find out how the error is produced. Maybe you'll get more information about what causes the problem.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

### OpenAPI Specification 2.0

In Swagger 2.0 ([OpenAPI Specification 2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-7)), use a form parameter (`in: formData`) with the `type` set to **file**. Additionally, the operation's `consumes` must be `multipart/form-data`.

```yaml
  consumes:
    - multipart/form-data
  parameters:
    - name: file
      in: formData   # <-----
      description: The uploaded file data
      required: true
      type: file     # <-----
```

### OpenAPI Specification 3.0

In [OpenAPI Specification 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#considerations-for-file-uploads), files are defined as binary strings, that is, `type: string` + `format: binary` (or `format: byte`, depending on the use case). File input/output content is described with the same semantics as any other schema type (unlike OpenAPI 2.0):

Multi-part request, single file:

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          # 'file' will be the field name in this multipart request
          file:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

Multi-part request, array of files (supported in Swagger UI 3.26.0+ and Swagger Editor 3.10.0+):

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          # The property name 'file' will be used for all files.
          file:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              format: binary
```

POST/PUT file directly (the request body is the file contents):

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    application/octet-stream:
      # any media type is accepted, functionally equivalent to `*/*`
      schema:
        # a binary file of any type
        type: string
        format: binary
```

Note: the semantics are the same as other OpenAPI 3.0 schema types:

```yaml
# content transferred in binary (octet-stream):
schema:
  type: string
  format: binary
```

Further information:

- [Considerations for File Uploads](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#considerations-for-file-uploads)
- [Special Considerations for multipart Content](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#special-considerations-for-multipart-content)
- [File Upload](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) and [Multipart Requests](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/)

Comment: How does one access the file in the node js controller? like if my file is called `filedata`, then my instream variable should be initialized to something like `req.swagger.params.filedata.value`? that gives me an error.

Comment: Can you please explain why the swagger OpenAPI specification is not pointing that out? https://swagger.io/specification/#considerations-for-file-uploads-61

Comment: @AmazingTurtle You linked to OpenAPI specification 3.0; I've updated the answer to include OpenAPI spec 3.0.

Comment: Can you explain more, e.g: when i use Django rest framework which module of code should be modified? thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71519777/multipart-file-upload-using-springfox-and-swagger-ui-upload-is-not-working

Answer (score 19):

finally i found answer for this, actually previously there is no support for **file upload**, now they updated **[swagger-ui.js](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/blob/1ec55a882983238d86ae76711474cfe67904970c/dist/swagger-ui.js)** file. You need to replace your old one with new and also you have to define these properties under Parameters for particular parameter:

```
 "paramType": "body",
 "dataType": "file",
```

Comment: This answer is for an older version of Swagger Specification (1.x?) and won't work in OpenAPI 2.0 / OpenAPI 3.0. See [mstrthealias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932354/113116) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Mine seems to work with

```
 "paramType": "formData",
 "dataType": "file",
```

Comment: This answer is for an older version of Swagger Specification (1.x?) and won't work in OpenAPI 2.0 / OpenAPI 3.0. See [mstrthealias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932354/113116) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Open API v 3.0.3

Here's what my swagger.json looks like:

```
"/media/upload": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["Media"],
        "name": "Upload Media",
        "description": "Uploads a Media file to the server.",
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "media": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "base64"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's how it shows up in swagger:

[image]

Comment: did you take above screenshot from aws api gateway developer portal. Even i created similar rest api, I'm not getting such option to choose file.

Comment: this is from my local machine