# swagger-node-express: How to upload file from swagger-ui?

Tags: node.js, curl, express, swagger, swagger-ui

Saw this q&a but did not have same results as OP [How to post files in swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455408/how-to-post-files-in-swagger)

Using this spec in my swagger-node-express API

```
exports.saveFile = {
  'spec' : {
    "description" : "Saves a file to filesystem",
    "path" : "/uploads/file",
    "notes" : "",
    "summary" : "POST a file to storage",
    "method" : "POST",
/*    "supportedContentTypes" : [ 'multipart/form-data' ],   */
    "produces":[ "application/json" ],
    "consumes":[ "multipart/form-data" ],
    "params" : [{
      "name": "File",
      "description": "The file to upload.",
      "paramType": "body",
      "required": true,
      "allowMultiple": false,
      "dataType": "file"
    }
    ],
    "responseClass" : "ArbitraryJson",
    "errorResponses" : [ errors.invalid('file') ],
    "nickname" : "saveFile"
  },
  'action' : function(req, res) {

    res.send('{"msg":"success", "file path": "' + req.files.file.path + '"}');

  }
};
```

When I POST via curl, `curl -v -F file=@scrot.png http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploads/file` everything works as expected.  When I post via swagger-ui (v 2.0.2) it fails.  I used a proxy in both situations and the swagger-ui isn't specifying the content-type nor is it passing the data.

Abbreviated raw post via curl (using command above)

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploads/file HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 43947
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------9af70f8a272c

------------------------------9af70f8a272c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="scrot.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
...
------------------------------9af70f8a272c--
```

Abbreviated raw post via swagger-ui

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploads/file HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/docs/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

How should I configure my route/spec so the swagger-ui will post correctly?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Running into the same thing.

Comment: Try setting the `"paramType"` to "form" rather than "body".

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, where I could do a POST with normal form values, but when I passed a file, I got no data. The issue for me was due to using Express 4, and not having multer installed and setup. Details can be found here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node-express/issues/202