# Swagger CSV Post

Tags: laravel, csv, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php

We are working on Swagger Documentation for our Laravel REST API implementation.
Several of the POST endpoints will use CSV as the parameter content type.

**Is there a way in Swagger to have the "Try It Now" function work with a CSV POST file upload?**

Below is our documentation in progress
http://api.curvecompass.com/docs/#/

We have the Laravel POST function working correctly with the CSV endpoint, just not the Swagger docs.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455408/how-to-post-files-in-swagger point you in the right direction?

Comment: You are using Swagger 2.0 or Swagger 3.0?

Comment: @TarunLalwani 3.0

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean that 1) an operation consumes `Content-Type: text/csv` and the response body is text formatted as CSV; 2) an operation is a file upload request ([`multipart/form-data`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8659808/113116)) that expects a CSV file as part of the multipart payload?

Comment: @Helen Currently we use Laravel  - we built an endpoint that accepts an HTML POST file that contains the CSV data. We want to add "Try It Now" functionality to our Swagger documentation that will accept a CSV file into the form data and pass it to the Laravel end point for ingestion.

Answer (score 0):

swagger ui for open api 3.0 does not support file upload yet. you can watch the update here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3641

Comment: That stinks. At this point I'd be willing to accept a hack if anyone has one to offer. Otherwise I'll just hack it myself. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
consumes:
    - multipart/form-data  # and/or application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  parameters:
    - name: file
      in: formData
      description: The uploaded file data
      required: true
      type: file
```