# Bad request content in swagger blocks file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, multipart

I'm using swagger blocks with rails. I one of the enpoint I have an image upload.

```
        parameter name: :tile_background_img,
                  in: :formData,
                  type: :file,
                  description: 'Tile background image'
```

On the swagger site it looks ok. If I add this image request has a header
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybl70oGERlw1hSmnH` and everything is fine.
When I use other params and leave image blank I got `EOFError Bad request content body` the header is
`Content-Type: text/html`
According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932354 I should add `consumes`. However in the docs this option is only in the general api settings and it's not working for me https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had to add `in: :formData` for other params in the request.