# File upload with swagger inflector and dropwizard

Tags: java, swagger, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

Im using swagger-inflector v.1.0.17 for my Java API. Here is what I built my API from: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/inflector-dropwizard-guice

My file upload API is defined:

```
'/orders-logo':
   post:
     x-swagger-router-controller: OrdersController
     tags:
       - orders
     summary: This API is upload a logo
     operationId: uploadLogo
     consumes:
       - multipart/form-data
     produces:
       - application/json
     parameters:
       - name: file
         in: formData
         description: file to upload
         required: false
         type: file
     responses:
       '200':
         description: Success
         schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/TokenView'
       '400':
         description: The request doesn't comply with the schema specified
         schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/ApiError'
       '401':
         description: Missing or invalid Authorization header
         schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/ApiError'
       '500':
         description: Internal server error while processing the request
         schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/ApiError'
```

And my method in the Controller:

```
public ResponseContext uploadLogo(RequestContext context, java.io.InputStream file) {
    ResponseContext response = new ResponseContext().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    System.out.println("in here");
}
```

And I'm trying the CURL:

```
curl -i -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbm9uXzU3MjBmMGUzLTMxMzItNDQ1OC1hYjYyLTBmY2EwMDEyMjAyNCIsImlzcyI6IkNsZXZlcmdpZnQiLCJleHAiOjE2MTY1MjEwMjMsImJhc2ljIjoidHJ1ZSIsIm1lcmNoYW50IjoiaGlnaHN0cmVldHZvdWNoZXJzIn0.s-yukQincZoWevQARLNrl57SABAetBxMCOF39RSd7a7tEnds5pIgo5ekRTQgX98MlEXFyDoHe0ws7iMIo_-cOQ' \
-H 'Api-Key: 7a34526370e2c3d4f2784f874aacbc0b' \
-F "file=@download.jpeg" "http://localhost:8080/v1/orders-logo"
```

But I get the response:

```
{"code":500,"message":"There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID: bad38eb089e2a71a)"}
```

And when I check the logs I see:

```
com.clevergift.dropwizard.InflectorExceptionMapper: There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID: bad38eb089e2a71a)
! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
! at io.swagger.inflector.controllers.SwaggerOperationController.apply(SwaggerOperationController.java:503)
! ... 67 common frames omitted
! Causing: io.swagger.inflector.utils.ApiException: There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID: bad38eb089e2a71a)
! at io.swagger.inflector.controllers.SwaggerOperationController.apply(SwaggerOperationController.java:560)
! at io.swagger.inflector.controllers.SwaggerOperationController.apply(SwaggerOperationController.java:89)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at com.clevergift.filters.ApiKeyFilter.doFilter(ApiKeyFilter.java:99)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at com.clevergift.filters.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:15)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:239)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:703)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:67)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:174)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
! at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [25/Jan/2021:16:12:03 +0000] "POST /v1/orders-logo HTTP/1.1" 500 110 "-" "curl/7.64.1" 5
```

Im using swagger-inflector version 1.0.17. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `/v1` prefix coming from?

Comment: Thats the url for my server. The requests are definitely hitting the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `uploadLogo` is being invoked instead of with a `java.io.InputStream` with a `java.io.File` argument, corresponding to the temporary file used by the framework for supporting the file upload.

This method is invoked by reflection in the `apply` method of `SwaggerOperationController`. When this invocation is performed, because the arguments are different - your method signature defines a `java.io.InputStream` but the framework is passing a `java.io.File` as argument - you are obtaining the indicated exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Please, try this signature instead:

```java
public ResponseContext uploadLogo(RequestContext context, java.io.File file) {
    ResponseContext response = new ResponseContext().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    System.out.println("in here");
    // The rest of your code
    return ...;
}
```

Please, note the change in the argument type.

Comment: That is great @Mark! I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you, and it's due to **version** of swagger and how file upload API is defined:

> Finally I found answer for this, actually previously there is no
> support for file upload, now they updated swagger-ui.js file. You need
> to replace your old one with new and also you have to define these
> properties under Parameters for particular parameter:

```
"paramType": "formData",
"dataType": "file",
```

It appears that the 404 Not Found response occurs when an operation returns a resource by ID and the parameter is invalid.

It may be that the parameter is not well defined or it cannot be found by this path.

Here is where I saw another post answers to a similar problem:
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455408/how-to-post-files-in-swagger-openapi)

**Update:**

From the error trace it looks like a Jackson or Jersey error when converting the parameter.

In development mode, there is a `/debug.json` page which shows implementation details of the inflector service.

If your Swagger Description is unparsable, the server will throw ugly errors on startup and the `debug.json` page will give indications as to why.

You can see this doc [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-inflector/tree/v1)

Comment: Updated question, actually Im getting a 500