# Multipart File upload using Springfox and Swagger-ui upload is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Spring Boot 2.6.4 and Spring Fox 3.0.0, I have a multipart file upload, but it is not appearing the button for uploading.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addDocument(@RequestPart (value = "files", required = true) MultipartFile[] multipartFiles)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
```

Here is how it appears on Swagger. Is it possible to use the button for uploading?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `MultipartFile` as a `RequestParam`, (`@RequestParam("attachments") MultipartFile[] attachments`)

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addDocument(@RequestParam ("files") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) throws IOException {

}
```

_

[image]

Comment: for me multiple file is not working.. don't know why.. single file is working fine but multiple upload file is not working

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to include the type of parameter in the method? eg:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addDocument(
    @Parameter(
        description = "Files to be uploaded", 
        content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    )
    @RequestPart (value = "files", required = true) MultipartFile[] multipartFiles)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
```

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am still having the same issue.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.6.4 and Spring Fox 3.0.0 and it works well thanks